# Floating Action Button null when inside a coordinatorlayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a FAB inside a coordinatorlayout. The objective was put a FAB anchor to a appbar that have a bottom navigation view as child, but the FAB just don't appear on screen and return a null object on class. The coordinatorlayout is in the same scope of a FragmentContainerView, and I guess that view is conflicting with the coordinatorlayout;

here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="Main.Main_Screen"
    >

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main"
        />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/main_bottom_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Laranja">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/Transparente"
                android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/Transparente"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_fast_sync"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/icones"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/Azul"
            app:borderWidth="0.7dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/main_bottom_bar"
            app:maxImageSize="38dp"
            app:tint="@null"
            />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the snippet where I am trying to instance a variable of the FAB:

```
fab_fast_sync = findViewById(R.id.fab_fast_sync);
fab_fast_sync.setOnClickListener(this); //returns a error by null object reference
```

I made a test on other project and its works perfectly fine without the FragmentContainerView, and reading the documentation about coordinatorlayout on developer.android I am clueless about my mistakes here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that I still don't know, the problem was in the XML file created with the class, after several tests, and the creation of a new activity and the replication of the code of the previous activity, the problem was solved, so I created a separate XML file. the context of the class that previously wasn't working with the old interface, so everything worked perfectly, however I'm still intrigued by the problem because I copied and pasted the XML code from the other file into the new one and it worked as it should.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).